# Autocomplete in Pycharm on templates

Tags: pycharm

Whenever I make a function, make it a view and map a template onto it, the auto-complete in PyCharm works. If you type in something like `{{ book. }}`, where `book` is a model, and is one of your context objects, then it will give you a drop-down menu with possible completions.

However, if you make a class based view, then this does not work. Any way that I can fix this?

Comment: You're talking about Django, right?

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem via a marginal method.

I'm using both PHPStorm and PyCharm and twig template engine most similar Tornado or DJango template engines syntax.

I've opened settings window/Plugins section. Clicked to "Install plugin form disk..." and selected ".../JetBrains/PhpStorm x.x/plugins/twig/lib/twig.jar"

Clicked "Ok"
Clicked "Apply"
And restarted "IDE"

template file name extension renamed to .twig and done!

[image: pycharm tornado template endgine via twig plugin]

Comment: The problem that I asked about in this question was solved in the new version 3. Thanks for the effort, though.