# Pycharm resolving references in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pycharm

Is it possible for PyCharm to resolve references in Django templates?  i.e., some code completion support, and when Ctrl + click on a template variable, we should go to the relevant python object.

The Jetbrains website boasts some impressive magic about Django templates:

> Code completion works for Django tags, filters, **template variables
>   and parameters passed from view methods**.

The review on [Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/pycharm-and-rubymine-review/228800986) confirms this functionality.  But I can't seem to get it to work:

[image]

I have setup the correct interpreter from my virtualenv, enabled Django Support in the settings and configured the templates directories, even invalidated and rebuilt the caches.

I'm on PyCharm v3.0.2.

Comment: I've not seen Go to -> Declaration work like that on templates. That's different than code completion, though.

Comment: FWIW, code completion doesn't work either (although it should if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16822164/674039) question can be trusted..)

Comment: In your `views.py` file, do you have a link to your HTML file next to your statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get this kind of functionality, you will need to see an icon on your `views.py` file, of the corresponding html file:

Using 3.0.2 here:

[image]

Either way, I will need to have a look at your directory and `views.py` file before I can tell you whats wrong with your source.

Comment: Thanks, I _don't_ see the icon in my views file.  What are the requirements for it to appear there?

Comment: I nuked the project and created it again from a fresh checkout, and now the gutter icons which take me automatically to the view are there (I'm not sure how, because the settings were all the same as I had previously!).  So that part is working now.  But I still don't have the names passed in context as clickable like you have in your picture here, what should I look at next?

Comment: @wim I've noticed that this functionality only seems to work with Class Based Views. For Function Based Views, it seems it cannot understand what is passed from view to template.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by figuring out that my settings.py file was not configured in `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Django`. Once I did that all intellisense clicked into place.

I've heard that this is a Pro-only feature but I cannot confirm that as I'm using a Pro license.